# How to resolve UIButton border issue after reload collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I have to apply border to UIButton which color matched with UIButton background color it's working fine but as I reload the collection view it apply to other button and next reload it apply to other. suppose if collection view reloads 3 Times then it's apply the border to 3 button which is wrong, it should only apply those button which background color matched with color variable color

Note:- at a time only one button can have border.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ChromazonColorCell", for: indexPath) as! ChromazonColorCell
    cell.configureData(data: colorSource[indexPath.row])
    cell.cellColorButton.tag = indexPath.row
    if color == colorSource[indexPath.row] {
        cell.cellColorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        cell.cellColorButton.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.cellColorButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell.cellColorButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: never do only if we have to provide else too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you.. when you reload collection view then it will reuse your cell. and your reused cell will have border so it is applied to other cells also.
please try below solution

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ChromazonColorCell", for: indexPath) as! ChromazonColorCell
  cell.configureData(data: colorSource[indexPath.row])
  cell.cellColorButton.tag = indexPath.row
  if color == colorSource[indexPath.row] {
    cell.cellColorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    cell.cellColorButton.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.cellColorButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.cellColorButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  }
else{
    cell.cellColorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    cell.cellColorButton.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.cellColorButton.layer.borderWidth = 0
    cell.cellColorButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
}
 return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dixit Rathod already answered.

but also, you can use your code and `prepareForReuse` method ***in your cell***:

```
func prepareForReuse(){ 
    super.prepareForReuse()

    cellColorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    cellColorButton.clipsToBounds = true
    cellColorButton.layer.borderWidth = 0
    cellColorButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
}
```